# input-group habilitar propiedades input

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
 <div class="input-group mb-3">
     <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
         <img class="image-input-info" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/480/000000/phone-not- 
         being-used.png" alt="Icono comentario crédito"/>
     </span>
     <input type="number" id="comentario_telefono" class="form-control" 
     name="comentario_telefono" onkeyup="copiar()"/>
 </div>
```

Como podrán ver tiene BOOTSTRAP, pero al momento de poner una función para limitar el length del input con id "comentario-telefono", BOOTSTRAP inhabilita toda la función que se quiera hacer, ya hice una prueba sin BOOTSTRAP y si funciona con el siguiente código:

```
<input type="number" id="telefono" />


document.getElementById("comentario_telefono").addEventListener("keyup", limitaTelefono);

function limitaTelefono() {
    var campo = document.getElementById("comentario_telefono");
    if (campo.value.length == 10) {
        campo.style.backgroundColor = "#E9ECEF";
        campo.disabled = true;
        campo.style.color = "#000";
    } else{

    }
}
```

No sé si me explique ¿?

Comment: Modifica el orden en que cargas tu scripts, pone el tuyo al final o agregale defer.

Comment: ¿Cómo "DEFER" Facundo?

Comment: en la etiqueta script, agregas defer de esta forma <script defer src="arhivo.js"></script>

Comment: No funciono con DEFER ¿Alguna otra manera? Ya revise y solo pasa con input=number con textarea sigue todo correcto por ejemplo

Comment: Intenta colocando `event.preventDefault()`; en tu función `limitaTelefono()`, por cierto, debes añadir `event` en tu función, así `limitaTelefono(event)`

Comment: No funciona,  Jhon Maldonado

Answer (score 0):

Tanto tu función, como el evento **keyup** los estás vinculando a un elemento con id **telefono** que en tu **HTML** no existe. Si te fijas el `<input>` de ejemplo tiene el id **comentario_telefono**. Además, ese `<input>` llama a una función llamada `copiar()` en su **keyup**. No puedes tener dos funciones asociadas al mismo evento.

```js
document.getElementById("telefono").addEventListener("keyup", limitaTelefono);

function limitaTelefono() {
    var campo = document.getElementById("telefono");
    if (campo.value.length == 10) {
        campo.style.backgroundColor = "#E9ECEF";
        campo.disabled = true;
        campo.style.color = "#000";
    } else{

    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
     <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
         <img class="image-input-info" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/480/000000/phone-not- 
         being-used.png" alt="Icono comentario crédito"/>
     </span>
     <input type="number" id="telefono" class="form-control" 
     name="telefono" />
 </div>
```

Si cambias el id en tu **HTML** al que corresponde y le quitas el evento **keyup** te debería funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Ah perdón, se me olvido modificar eso, tenia otro input con id "telefono" de prueba, igual buena explicación phpMyguel

Comment: En mi ejemplo ejecutable he cargado Bootstrap para que veas que ese no es el problema. ¿Lo que muestras en tu pregunta es lo que tienes en tu proyecto?

Comment: Sí, de hecho acabo de pasar los links de bootstrap a mi proyecto pero aún así no surte efecto

Comment: Pues el problema son esas dos cosas que te he dicho. en tu elemento `<input type="number" id="comentario_telefono" class="form-control" name="comentario_telefono" onkeyup="copiar()"/` tienes una función keyup ya. No puedes tener las dos. (copiar() y limitaTelefono())

Comment: Quite la copiar(); pero no funciona tampoco

Comment: como veo que si funciona un textarea colocare uno y le dare estilo de input, igual estoy revisando todas sus respuestas

Comment: En mi ejemplo, como ves funciona el limitador. Algo tienes que no no has puesto y que te está afectando.